# Error (wrong-type-argument stringp ) al crear una lista en Emacs

Tags: emacs, lisp

Estoy tratando de crear una lista de rutas en Emacs, pero tengo este error que no sé cómo corregir.

En el buffer `scratch` evalúo las siguientes expresiones:

```lisp
(setq files (list "d:/Users/javier/Documents/org/trabajo.org" ))
(message files)
```

Y obtengo el siguiente error:

```lisp
eval-buffer: Wrong type argument: stringp, ("d:/Users/javier/Documents/org/trabajo.org")
```

¿Cómo debo crear mi variable `files` con el valor indicado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás creando una lista con un único elemento, que es de tipo string.

Entonces, para poder desplegar ese primer elemento usando `message`, debes seleccionar ese elemento. 2 formas:

```
(message (car files))
(message (nth 0 files))
```

Donde `car` toma el primer elemento de la lista, y `nth` toma un elemento arbitrario.

Si `files` sólo va a contener un único valor, entonces no hay que crear una lista:

```
(setq files2 "/home/toto/ejemplo.txt")
(message files2)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu explicación.